# Whats is the fastest way to remotely restart (redial) the router?

Tags: windows-7, router, wifi

I have a Belkin F5D7234-4 Wireless G router. The router is connected to DSL modem. I wanted to know if there is anyway to remotely restart or redial the router. Since my ISP provides dynamic IP I need to somehow restart the router so that it re-dials the connection and I get a new IP.

There is one way I can think of. I can go to admin page of the router and then give restart. However it takes 30s to start up. Is there any faster way ? Or a 3rd party application which supports that ?
Thanks.

Comment: Using a different tool isn't going to make the router reboot any faster.

Comment: @Joeqwerty: does if you kick it hard enough.

Comment: @Bart: Right. I've got a hammer and everything is a nail. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not really. SOHO class routers aren't big on processing power, and aren't made for fast reboot times. They're also not meant for tinkering so it's difficult to script or access them with tools for management.

If you wanted you could try replacing your setup with a computer running Linux, or one of the Linux projects that will flash your router with a new OS and it might be faster and more functional.

You seem to have two issues here but don't state why the requirement is such; you wanted to know if you can remotely restart the router, which you can with the web interface or a power product that you plug into your power outlet and then plug the router into that then remotely flick power on and off to the router. So yes, you can get it to reinitialize. (Alternatively you can find an application that will script the procedure for restarting from a computer on your network.)

Then you mentioned it takes 30+ seconds to restart it. Is there a reason you need it up ASAP, or just impatience? Even our Cisco routers can take a couple minutes to come back up if power is cycled on them. Most routers aren't meant to restart so it's not a common occurrence, in turn boot time isn't a priority or feature to manufacturers.

EDIT:I'll also add that even if you script it or find another way to do the reboot, the more complexity you add to the "system" the greater the chance you'll be increasing headaches down the road. Technology tasks should be as simple as possible before the odds of failure tip the scale into being a pain, and doing something like coming up with a script on a computer to attempt a reboot of the router only increases the chances that something will go wrong.

If you absolutely need to keep it up all the time without changing addresses, you might want to contact your provider about getting a static IP. Depends on what your situation is and how important these headaches are for you to avoid.

Comment: +1 "Not really. SOHO class routers aren't big on processing power, and aren't made for fast reboot times. They're also not meant for tinkering so it's difficult to script or access them with tools for management."

Answer (score 0):

Bart did a good job of explaining the boot speed part of your question. One other thing would be if you can request a new WAN IP it might be faster than going through the entire reboot process

If you can telnet or ssh into the device it should be pretty easy to log in and perform a restart or if you have access, request a new IP address. Keep security in mind since if you can reach a config page over the WAN connection others can as well.

You mentioned that you do have HTTP access to the router. When you issue a reboot from the web interface see what the actual URL for this is. It should be possible to mimic the POST or GET request pretty easily through a script so that you do not have to log into the router each time to reboot it. I often end up doing things like this to manage several SOHO routers at once and it seems to work out pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately if it's the type of Belkin router I'm thinking it is, it's a home combo router (wireless+switch+router) that is meant for the ~$100 or less home market (SOHO router). I hated those things since usually I'd end up having either the switch or the wireless part die on me then I'd end up replacing it in a few months to a year...anyway, they usually only have a proprietary web interface, no telnet or ssh on them. Unless you reflash it with Linux.